# assert Json Validation Errors does not work

Tags: json, laravel, validation, phpunit

I am not an expert and I could not find anything about my error. I hope someone can help me to understand my error.

I am trying to test the validation of the required attributes of a POST request in Laravel.

**TEST**

I am using the `assertJsonValidationErrors` method to validate the JSON errors from my controller.

```
/** @test */
public function name_email_password_required_in_creation()
{
    $response = $this->post('/users', [
        'contact' => '545678987'
    ]);
    $response->assertJsonValidationErrors(['name','password','email']);
}
```

**Controller**

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|unique:users,email',
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json($validator->errors(), 400);
    }
```

Error:

**1) Tests\Feature\UsersTest::name_email_password_required_in_creation**
**Failed to find a validation error in the response for key: 'name'**

**Response does not have JSON validation errors.
Failed asserting that an array has the key 'name'.**

I applied inside the test a

`dd($response->getContent());` to see what is happening and in the response is:

`"{"name":["The name field is required."],"email":["The email field is required."],"password":["The password field is required."]}"`

It seems to be a **string** but I don't know if it is causing the error, because the JSON contains the key fields errors.

I do know how to solve it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this:

```
$response = $this->post('/users', [
    'contact' => '545678987'
]);
```

Use headers to accept json like this:

```
$response = $this->json('POST', '/users', ['contact' => '545678987'],
    ['Accept' => 'application/json']
);
```

Also for validation errors the response code is 422, so use:

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
    return response()->json($validator->errors(), 422);
}
```

Comment: My service override the response and is 400. I ll try the header Accept but the response is to validate de information structure. not just the header