# Laravel: Feature test json validations unique rule issue

Tags: laravel, testing, phpunit, unique, rules

I recently started implementing the unit testing in `Laravel 9.x` framework. So far, I was able to write some basic rules without any complications. However, in my application I am validating the forms using `ajax` and `From Request` for validation rules.

#### `CategoryRequest.php`

```php
class CategoryRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            // ...

            'title' => [
                'required',
                'max:255',
                function($attributes, $value, $fails) {
                    $Category = Category::where([
                        'user_id' => request()->user_id,
                        'title'   => request()->title,
                    ])->first();

                    if($Category) {
                        $fails('`Category` is already taken');
                    }
                }
            ],

        // ...
        ];
    }
}
```

#### `CategoryTest.php`

```php
class CategoryTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;

    // ...

    public function test_new_category_with_unique_validation()
    {
        $user = $this->__user();
        $arrayPost = [
            'user_id' => $user->id,
            'uuid'    => Str::uuid(),
            'title'   => 'title',
            'status'  => STATUS['active'],
        ];

        Category::factory()->create($arrayPost);

        $response = $this
            ->actingAs($user)
            ->post('/console/categories', $arrayPost);

        $response->assertJsonValidationErrorFor('title');
        $response->assertJsonValidationErrorFor('status');
        $response->assertJsonValidationErrorFor('uuid');
        $response->assertJsonValidationErrorFor('user_id');
    }

    private function __user(): object
    {
        return User::factory()->create();
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error...

[image: error]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to add `$this->withExceptionHandling();` in your test method.

Comment: @xuma that would be the solution, but if the author needs to do so, then something is wrong, as that is the default behavior and should never be changed, because this will happen

Comment: @xuma, I tried your suggestion but unfortunately id didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here [assert Json Validation Errors does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57839251/assert-json-validation-errors-does-not-work)

Also, I have created the separate tests for each validation. Therefore, this test only focuses on the `unique title` validation now.

```php
class CategoryTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;

    // ...

    public function test_new_category_with_unique_title_validation()
    {
        $user = $this->__user();

        Category::factory()->create([
            'user_id' => $user->id,
            'uuid'    => Str::uuid(),
            'title'   => 'title',
            'status'  => STATUS['active'],
        ]);

        $response = $this->actingAs($user)->json('POST', '/console/categories', [
            'title'  => 'title',
            'status' => STATUS['active'],
        ], [
            'Accept' => 'application/json'
        ]);

        $response->assertJsonValidationErrorFor('title');
    }

    private function __user(): object
    {
        return User::factory()->create();
    }
}
```